# Javascript read JSONArray in Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring-mvc

I have an array of objects like

```
var word_list = [
       {text: "halo", weight: 2, link:"a"},
       {text: "hey", weight: 3, link:"a"},
       {text: "cat", weight: 2, link:"a"},
       {text: "dog", weight: 4, link:"a"},
    ];
```

I want to use ajax to receive this var from Controller:

```
function get(){
         $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"readTagCloud",
           contentType: 'application/json'
           datatype : "json",
           success:function(data) {
               word_list = data;
           },
           error: function() {}
 });
 }
```

code of Controller:

```
@RequestMapping("readTagCloud")
    @ResponseBody
    public String readTagCloud(String topicId,Integer emotion){
        JSONArray words = new JSONArray();
        for(int i = 0;i<10;i++){
            JSONObject word = new JSONObject();
            try {
                word.put("text", i+"");
                word.put("weight", i/2);
                word.put("link", "none");
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            words.put(word);
        }
        return words.toString();
    }
```

But，when ajax work，it make the word_list become String type.I want to know how to read JSONArray in Spring MVC

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use: [`JSON.parse`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse):

```
word_list = JSON.parse(word_list)
```